# How to pass string variable inside to_timestamp() in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, to-timestamp

I have a query like this:

```
select from_tz(to_timestamp(v_time,'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'UTC') 
      at time zone 'America/New_York' from dual;
```

If I use a string Date instead of v_time then it works fine. But I need to pass a variable v_time inside to_timestamp, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

The full code is here:

```
DECLARE
     v_test varchar2(200);
     v_cur_time varchar2(200);
     v_local_strem_time varchar2(200);
     v_time varchar2(200);
     v_time_diff NUMBER(20);
      v_temp varchar2(200);
     BEGIN

    SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') into v_cur_time
    FROM DUAL;

    select substr(((select TO_CHAR(date_time,'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from observation_measurement where observation_measurement_id=5777992)), 1,17)
    into v_time  from dual;

    v_temp := v_time;
    select from_tz(to_timestamp(v_temp,'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'UTC') 
    at time zone 'America/New_York' into v_local_strem_time from dual;

      select 24 * (to_date(v_cur_time, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
             - to_date(v_local_strem_time, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) into v_time_diff 
       from dual;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_time_diff); 
    END;
```

Comment: What is the datatype of  `v_time` , `VARCHAR` or `DATE` ?

Answer (score -1):

the variable must be `declared`(in a `code block` or in a `procedure` or in a `function` or etc)

```
declare 
v_time varchar(20);
outval timestamp;
begin
v_time := '15-02-20 07:13:10';
select from_tz(to_timestamp(v_time,'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'UTC') 
      at time zone 'America/New_York' into outval from dual;
dbms_output.put_line(outval);
end;
```

**OUTPUT:**  20-FEB-15 02.13.10.000000 AM

**EDIT AFTER EDDITING QUESTION:**
the problem is with `v_local_strem_time` which contains `AMERICA/NEW_YORK` string , one way is use the `SUBSTR` function to remove the unnecessary string. let me to test it:

---

```
Create table observation_measurement(
observation_measurement_id number,
date_time date
)
```

---

```
insert into observation_measurement
values (5777992,to_date('214/10/09', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

---

```
DECLARE
     v_test varchar2(200);
     v_cur_time varchar2(200);
     v_local_strem_time varchar2(200);
     v_time varchar2(200);
     v_time_diff NUMBER(20);
     v_temp varchar2(200);
     BEGIN

    SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') into v_cur_time
    FROM DUAL;

    select substr(((select TO_CHAR(date_time,'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from observation_measurement where observation_measurement_id=5777992)), 1,17)
    into v_time  from dual;

    v_temp := v_time;
    select from_tz(to_timestamp(v_temp,'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'UTC') 
    at time zone 'America/New_York' into v_local_strem_time from dual;

      select 24 * (to_date(v_cur_time, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
             - to_date(substr(v_local_strem_time,0,18), 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) into v_time_diff 
       from dual;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_time_diff); 
    END;
```

---

**OUTPUT:** 143241

Also maybe the datatype of `observation_measurement.date_time` of your structure is not date, at that time you may need to do appropriate converts.

Comment: @Ferheg: I edit the question with full code. Although I declared the variable in the code block still it is showing error like: "date format picture ends before converting entire input string". I got the v_time variable from another query. Please see the edited question.

Comment: @Novis answer edited, you can check it, sorry for the delay I was busy.